# How to send a local image instead of URL to Microsoft Cognitive Face API using JAVA

Tags: java, azure-cognitive-services

Am trying to play with Face API of Microsoft Cognitive Services. Am wondering how to send a local image through rest API calls to Face API and request for the results from it using **JAVA**. Can anyone help me with this please?

The Testing opting provided by Microsoft on their site only takes URL, I Tried to convert my local path to URL and give it as input but that doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what part of "their site" you're looking at. From "Microsoft Cognitive Services - Documentation", https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api/documentation/get-started-with-face-api/gettingstartedwithfaceapiinjavaforandroid , it looks like te `detect` method takes an `InputSteam` containing a JPEG-format image.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `FileEntity` class.

```
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Face
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect");

            builder.setParameter("returnFaceId", "true");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "YOUR_KEY");


            // Request body
            File file = new File("YOUR_FILE");
            FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, "application/octet-stream");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with FileEntity seems to be the most elegant way of solving the problem. There has been a small change to ctrash's code: Since the constructor `FileEntity(File, String)` has deprecated, the constructor `FileEntity(File, ContentType)` has to be used. In this case, the Content Type of both the header and the image file has to be "application/octet-stream". I got it to work with this Code:

```
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class PostTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect");

            uriBuilder.setParameter("returnFaceId", "true");
            uriBuilder.setParameter("returnFaceLandmarks", "false");
            uriBuilder.setParameter("returnFaceAttributes", "age");

            URI uri = uriBuilder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);

            // Request headers. Replace the example key below with your valid subscription key.
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY");



            // Request body


            File file = new File("YOUR_IMAGE_FILE");

            FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

            if (entity != null)
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

After correct execution, the terminal will show the JSON object the Face API returns.

Thank you, cthrash, for this is the only place in the internet where I learned how to do this!