# Adding a local path to Microsoft Face API by Python

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsoft Face API for a small project and I was trying to detect a face inside a .jpg file in the local system (say, stored in a directory *D:\Image\abc.jpg*)

The example code, as shown in their [documentation](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236), works very well on url from online sources, but it does not seem to work for local path address. I have tried to do the following:

```
dict = "{ 'url' : 'file:///D:/Image/abc.jpg'}"
```

But it does not seem to work. It seems that there is a method for Java (using [FileEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541634/how-to-send-a-local-image-instead-of-url-to-microsoft-cognitive-face-api-using-j)). I'm wondering if there is a method for Python. I'm new to coding. I really hope someone can help me with this. I'm using Python3.

Comment: Sending a local filename to the API  isn't going to work, you need to send the actual file data.Those docs say you need to change the request `Content-Type` header from "application/json" to "application/octet-stream", and send the binary data of the file in the request body. There's an example on [this MSDN page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5d72a95-3a44-48bb-b5c9-b261e811d4d9/using-face-api-with-python-and-local-image-files?forum=mlapi). The code there isn't great, but it should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft cannot read files from your local file system because they are not publicly on the internet in the way that images accessible from URLs are. Therefore you need to send the file to the Microsoft Face API for them to access it.

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 
           'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': <token>}
url = 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect'

# Gets the binary file data so we can send it to MCS
data = open('file:///D:/Image/abc.jpg', 'rb')
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Hi! Can you help me? I copied your code and i have error : OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'file:///D:\\face.jpg'

Comment: @True-hacker change the open url to like this:
`data = open('D:/Image/abc.jpg', 'rb').read()
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)`
you can read more details [here](https://code.likeagirl.io/beginners-guide-to-using-mcs-face-api-pt2-7be61d23ed4e)